# If $\sum a_k^2$ and $\sum b_k^2$ converge: does $\sum (a_n)(b_n)$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Show that if a sequence $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ of non-negative terms is such that $\sum a_k^2$ converges and $\sum b_k^2$ converges then $\sum (a_n)(b_n) $ converges?

Honestly not too sure where to start
Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Or simply $0\leq ab\leq \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in comment, 
$$\sum _na_n b_n \le \left(\sum_na_n^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\sum_nb_n^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I get it. You can use basic comparison test to show that it must converge

Comment: $\sum_(a_n^2)$ converges doesn't imply that $\sum_(a_n)$ converges so how would you go about proving the the second part of the inequality does converge

Comment: I don't have $\sum a_n$ anywhere in the inequality

Comment: Never mind sorry I get it